# Trouble converting to datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I am trying to convert using strptime and for the life of me cannot figure this out

`'07-17-2019 23:39 PM GMT-4' does not match format '%m-%d-%y %H:%M %p %z'`

Thank you for any help

Comment: Relevant documentation: [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-strptime-behavior) (see the table of directives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I've found that `%y` should be `%Y`. The best way to approach this is to test it a bit at a time. Like starting with `datetime.strptime('07-17-2019', '%m-%d-%Y')`. There's also something wrong with the GMT-4. %z will match -0400 fine, and %Z will match UTC, EST, and others, which might be better than an offset if you want to include daylight savings time, but it looks like that's all you get with `strptime`.

`dateutil.parser.parse` might provide you with more options and flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this, which is not super flexible, but should have a bit of give.

Firstly, a few points:

1. `%y` should be `%Y`, to match a 4-digit year.
2. Using a 24-hour time with AM/PM is confusing, so let's just ignore the AM/PM.
3. `GMT-4` is not a standard timezone name, so we need to handle it manually.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import datetime

s = '07-17-2019 23:39 PM GMT-4'

fmt = '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M'  # Excludes AM/PM and timezone on purpose

words = s.split()

# Get just date and time as a string.
s_dt = ' '.join(words[:2])
# Convert date and time to datetime, tz-unaware.
unaware = datetime.datetime.strptime(s_dt, fmt)

# Get GMT offset as int - assumes whole hour.
gmt_offset = int(words[3].replace('GMT', ''))
# Convert GMT offset to timezone.
tz = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=gmt_offset))

# Add timezone to datetime
aware = unaware.replace(tzinfo=tz)

print(aware)  # -> 2019-07-17 23:39:00-04:00
```

P.s. I used these to reverse-engineer a bit of it

```
tz = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=-4))
dt = datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 17, 23, 39, tzinfo=tz)
```